# Odd delay when making service-to-service calls on Google Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-run

I have 2 simple services written in Go deployed on Cloud Run region **us-central1** and I'm experiencing an odd delay when I have one service call the other.

Here's the code:

[test1.go](https://gist.github.com/anrid/a3510f93dd7570d842e8a99ef5e5ec4a)

[test2.go](https://gist.github.com/anrid/ee21774332991f420449e360bcae03e4)

I deploy the two services as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"

deploy () {
  gcloud beta run deploy $1 \
    --image "${2}/project-x/serverless-test/${1}" \
    --platform managed \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --region $3 \
    --async
}

deploy "test1" "gcr.io" "us-central1"
deploy "test2" "gcr.io" "us-central1"
```

Once deployed, I have service `test1` call service `test2` 10 times in a row like so:

https://test1-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app/?url=https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app

Which produces the following output:

```
{
  "message": "Hello, World! Took 2.083242593s",
  "ok": true,
  "responses": [
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #1 : received 5 bytes in 209.859893ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #2 : received 5 bytes in 207.109789ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #3 : received 5 bytes in 206.209135ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #4 : received 5 bytes in 207.54638ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #5 : received 5 bytes in 208.772364ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #6 : received 5 bytes in 206.981902ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #7 : received 5 bytes in 211.108579ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #8 : received 5 bytes in 207.932876ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #9 : received 5 bytes in 208.195697ms",
    "called https://test2-sfh32yualq-uc.a.run.app #10 : received 5 bytes in 209.33479ms"
  ]
}
```

Now for the odd parts;

a) I would expect the response times of `test1` calling `test2` *in the same region* to be *much lower*.

b) I get ~150ms average response times when I call `test2` using Chrome *from Yokohama, Japan*, i.e from across the pacific:

[calling test2 from Japan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS6Dh.png)

Service `test2` seems to perform as expected when being called directly via a browser, but performs slowly when called from within `test1`.

The Cloud Run logs seem to confirm this:

[Could Run Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKBpU.png)

Comment: There is no code in your question, so we have nothing to review. As a suggestion try deploying to us-central1 and compare. There was an issue with asia, I am not sure if that was resolved.

Comment: When you perform your test, is the first time after deploying (and cause cold start)? or the behavior is the same many times in sequence (even with warm container) ?

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for the prompt answer! I managed to solve this by just running the service a lot more often. The response times then dropped to expected levels. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere you were on the right track there, response times did drop after I started running the service a lot more often. Seems a bit tricky to keep the service "warm". Thank you!

Comment: What region are you using for the container image? Google Cloud Console Container Registry will show you the location under hostname.

Comment: @JohnHanley I'm pushing my images to gcr.io.

And I may have spoken too soon, I still can't get service-to-service calls to perform as expected.

Calling [https://test1-sfh32yualq-an.a.run.app/](https://test1-sfh32yualq-an.a.run.app/) takes about 4.5 seconds, and all that service does is call [https://test2-sfh32yualq-an.a.run.app/](https://test2-sfh32yualq-an.a.run.app/) 10 times.

Calling [https://test2-sfh32yualq-an.a.run.app/](https://test2-sfh32yualq-an.a.run.app/) directly gives a response in around 30ms.

These services are deployed on the `asia-northeast1` region.

Comment: Your containers are located halfway across the world. Put your container images in Container Registry in Asia `asia.gcr.io`

Comment: Also, test using us-central1 for Cloud Run to compare.

Comment: I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: fwiw, CloudRun implements most parts of the knative serving API and one key configuration of that is it's ability to scale to zero, when not under any load. That's how Google helps you ensure you're not paying for any running instances while your app isn't serving requests and from a quick glance at my CloudRun on GKE, I see the instance could be shut down after 1min, hence you'd experience the cold start when next you're trying to reach the app. To keep your services warm, you'd probably need a polling system that makes a request to the app regularly. You can try the Cloud Scheduler for that.